# Long running http GET in Lambda times out

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm hoping to use Lambda to get a master list and save it to s3 on a regular interval. I've got this working with quickly running GET requests, but for the actual data file i need to get, the ultimate result is a premature exit because it take a while to GET the full contents.

```
'use strict';
let http = require('http');


/**
 * get the data and store it in S3
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("STARTING?");
    let aws = require('aws-sdk');
    aws.config.region = 'us-west-2';

    let s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });


    var url = "http://long.running.url";

    // do the request of the company list
    http.get(url, (res) => {

        var body = "";

        console.log(`Got response: ${res.statusCode}`);

        // consume response body
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
            //console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.')

            // S3
            var param = {
                Bucket: 'my/s3/bucket',
                Key: 'big.masterlist.txt',
                Body: body
            };
            s3.putObject(param, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error", err);
                }
                console.log(data);
                context.done(null, data);
            });

        });

    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    });

};
```

This results in `{"errorMessage":"Process exited before completing request"}`

I'm not sure if this is a legit timeout or something else. What could it be?

Comment: What version of node? 6.x+ by chance?

Comment: @Joe it says node 4.3

Answer (score 2):

In Amazon's [Lambda FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/):

> Q: How long can an AWS Lambda function execute?
>
> All calls made to AWS Lambda must complete execution within 300
>   seconds. The default timeout is 3 seconds, but you can set the timeout
>   to any value between 1 and 300 seconds.

The timeout can be adjusted using `UpdateFunctionConfiguration`, described in [Amazon's Lambda documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html).